# Node js, MongoDB Atlas query based on params value returning all documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to mongoDB and I am trying to query a collection to return 1 object based on a specific value. It seems that the query is ignoring my search terms {field: value} and just returning all the documents available within the collection. I am using node & express and testing using Postman.

This is the code I am trying now but I have tried multiple methods. I am getting all the documents returned but I am expecting only one where the user: is equal to the params.

```
const db = require('../Models/Device');

//Get device where user email = params
DeviceRouter.get("/:email", async (req, res) => {
    var query = {"user": {$eq: req.params.email}};
    try{
        var cursor = await db.find(query);
        res.json(cursor);
    } catch {
        res.json(cursor);
    }
});
```

I have also tried this, again, same result.

```
`DeviceRouter.get("/:email", async (req, res) => {
    var query = {user: req.params.email};
    try{
        var cursor = await db.find(query);
        res.json(cursor);
    } catch {
        res.json(cursor);
    }
}); `
```

I have also tried putting the query directly in the find as such find({user: req.params.email});

again, same result

This is my document structure within the collection

```
`_id: objectId ('64174dff4fc6e7836acab7ac')
code: "AA106"
enclosure: "AA106"
user: "test@live.co.uk"`
```

Code used to connect to the database, the URI is the connection string from MongoDB atlas.

```
const deviceRoute = require('./Routes/devices');
//for use with devices 
app.use('/device', deviceRoute);

//Connect to database
dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.URI, () => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

Also inside the const db = require('../Models/Device'); as shown at the very top is the Shema

```
const DeviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Device: {
        code: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        enclosure: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        user: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        }
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Devices', DeviceSchema);
```

Comment: Use the method findOne({user: req.params.email})

Comment: Take a look at the example here -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/

 - Are you trying to fetch the right collection? - What is the result when you give static value for mail, e.g. query = { user: "test@live.co.uk" };

Comment: When I give a static value such as you have demonstrated, it again returns every document within the collection

Comment: Can you please add lines in your project to the question that you created db connection and selected the collection?

Comment: Could it be because you have "Device" key defined before code, enclosure and user keys? Does the behavior change if you remove Device key or having query as "Device.user"?